# Java ScheduleExpression: Scheduler works only the first hour, why?

Tags: java, scheduler

This is my first using of ScheduleExpression, the documentation seems easy to understand but I can't do with it what I'm supposed to do. 
My need is very simple :

- Simple scheduler to run every 15 minute starting at minute 10.
- My ScheduleExpression object is declared like this :

  ```
  ScheduleExpression scheduleExpression = new ScheduleExpression();
  scheduleExpression.second("0").minute("10/15").hour("*");
  ```

That work perfectly the first hour but only the first hour, so i can't understand why doesn't work during all hours of the day.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html): "*Note that the set of matching increment values **stops** once the maximum value for that attribute is exceeded. It **does not "roll over"** past the boundary.*"

Comment: Thanks for your comment and also your the review of my post.
so must i replace hour(*) by hour("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,....,24") ?

Comment: like this hour("[0,23]") @BenTayaa